# How to embed two .rdlc files in mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc

I am using asp.net MVC 3.

Below is my requirement.

Database:
I have a table called "Employee". In that I have columns like "EmpID, EmpName, Gender, Salary".

Controller:

In controller I have a action method called GetEmployee. In this action method i'm fetching data from "Employee" table. My requirement is, now I need to display all male employee information in one .rdlc file which is "Male.rdlc" and Female information in another .rdlc file which is "Female.rdlc". It means that both (Male.rdlc and Female.rdlc) files embed together into single rdlc so that it prints in a single file.

How can I achieve this??

Please can you give me with code example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do ANYTHING you want within your rdlc. Actually, you can have several datasource (table, view, stroed procedure etc...) in the dataset on which your rdlc is based (in you case you can have Male table and Female table in your dataset). From that you can build your rdlc report with the information you'd like.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. Actually I need to embed both Male rdlc and Female rdlc together so that end user will print both at once. Please help.

Comment: Did you solve it yet ? ... People won't answer nor post code for you... Read "How to ask questions" post of stackoverflow... Anyways, if I recall properly, the dataset of an rdlc report can contain multiple data sources (or if you want table/view/storedprocedure sources). So you can have different datasource for male and female in your rdlc dataset and from there draw you rdlc report fields using the dataset fields as you wish

Comment: Yes...I solved this